# Reduce video size/quality in android

Tags: java, android, video, resize

I've been looking for this for some time now but I couldn't find anything useful. Is there a way to reduce the size / resize of an existing video in android? I want to send it via the network.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built into Android for this. You are welcome to research third party code that might do this for you. Bear in mind that most Android devices run on low-power CPUs and have relatively slow flash memory, and so re-sizing a video may take a very long time.